# How can I relatively position this overlapping view?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am finding it impossible to produce my desired layout in android studio.
I have a very simple gimmick drawing app and I'm trying to add a colour palette as a gridView.  The palette is too big to not overlap the canvas, so I'd like to show it while the colour button is pressed so you can swipe to your desired colour.

Positioning the palette gridview is proving difficult.  I would like it overlapping the canvas, above and horizontally centred with the 'pencil' colour selection button.  I've tried two methods:

- Having the gridview exist in the top-level relative layout, so it can easily overlap the canvas.  This is as per the screenshot.  However, I can't position it relative to the button here because the button is in a different layout.
- Having the relative layout containing button and palette contained in the control view, as shown in the tree diagram.  However, the palette won't draw outside its parent layout, and the relativeview can't overlap the canvas because it's in the linear layout for controls which goes beneath the canvas.

It seems like such a trivial thing - is it really impossible?  Should I abandon all pretense of linear layouts and place everything in one relative layout?

[Tree diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x57an.png)

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Please add your xml layout file for a better understanding

Comment: open your activity_main.xml file there you will get your ans which contain your container_main with a fab on it . Or you can paste your xml

Comment: I've tried a thousand different XML layouts, but since none of them work I wouldn't know which to post.  The elements are as simple as you see; one canvas, three buttons on the same horizontal line, and what I desire is the palette gridView's central vertical to be aligned with that of the pencil button.